# Cannot install jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, installation, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Every time I load `jupyter notebook` I get the error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Kris\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I reinstalled Pycharm, Python and  Conda but the issue persists.

When running `pip install jupyter`,  I do get some installation but it errors out at

```
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2>=2.4->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/2e/64db92e53b86efccfaea71321f597fa2e1b2bd3853d8ce658568f7a13094/MarkupSafe-1.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core->nbconvert->jupyter) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" (from jupyter-core->nbconvert->jupyter)
```

How can I get Jupyter to install?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda. The recommended install which I did originally doesn't set pathways.  So the other install method sets pathways automatically but u have to have admin access.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: `python -m pip install jupyter` and then `python -m jupyter notebook`.